# indentation of multiline string

Tags: python, cmd, indentation

I have a script that uses the cmd Python module. The cmd module uses a triple quoted multiline string as it's help text. Something like this

```
def x(self, strags = None):
    """class
    help text here
    and some more help text here"""
```

When running the script, the command 'help x' will print the string. It will, however, print the newlines in front of the last two lines as well. I can overcome this by not indenting these lines, but that'll make my code ugl{y,ier}.

How to overcome this indenting problem? How do the pro Python coders handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I try to follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which refers the reader to [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for Docstring Conventions. It has an entire section on multi-line docstrings.

Comment: Although this is always a good idea, this does not solve the problem asked. The indentation trimming which usually occurs in docstrings does not seem to occur in the cmd module's help test. This could be a bug in the module unless there is some way to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle it by having consistent indents, like this:

```
def x(self, strags = None):
    """
    class
    help text here
    and some more help text here
    """
```

Sure, it takes two lines more, but it also injects clarity (in my opinion) by making the doc comment stand out quite well.